# Thread state change timing relative to lock release

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Does a thread state change, from Blocked to Runnable, only happen once the lock (on which the thread is blocked) is released?  Or does it happen before the lock is acquired by the thread?

After posting this, I found out about wait sets.  Now I'm inclined to think the timing of the state change is independent of the timing of lock acquisition/release.  But I'd still like validation of this from someone more experienced.

Comment: What do you intend to do with this information? I would imagine it happens after the lock is acquired by the blocked thread.

Comment: I don't have an immediate practical use for the answer.  I'm building a mental model of Java threading, and this arose in my mind as a question I could not answer with confidence based on what I already know.

Comment: Why do you think it has to be either one or the other.  Why can't it happen after the lock is released by its previous owner, AND before it is acquired by the previously blocked thread?

Comment: @jameslarge I think my question covers what you describe, since release must always precede acquisition.